# Js getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined but still working

Tags: javascript, audio

I have some javascript that grabs coordinates from an array.

The error I am getting is in retrieving the right and left coordinates of the variable.

The error is

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'rightX' of undefined
```

the code is

```
var notesArray = ["A","Bf","B","C","Cs","D","Ef","E","F","Fs","G","Gs"];

notesArray["A"]  = {leftX : 0, rightX : 320, topY : 0, bottomY : 240, color : "#ffffff"};
notesArray["Bf"] = {leftX : 0, rightX : 320, topY : 240, bottomY : 480, color : "#ffffff"};
notesArray["B"]  = {leftX : 320, rightX : 640, topY : 0, bottomY : 240, color: "#ffffff"};
notesArray["C"]  = {leftX : 0, rightX : 320, topY : 480, bottomY : 720, color: "#ffffff"};
notesArray["Cs"] = {leftX : 320, rightX : 640, topY : 240, bottomY : 480, color: "#ffffff"};
notesArray["D"]  = {leftX : 640, rightX : 960, topY : 0, bottomY : 240, color: "#ffffff"};
notesArray["Ef"] = {leftX : 320, rightX : 640, topY : 480, bottomY : 720, color: "#ffffff"};
notesArray["E"]  = {leftX : 640, rightX : 960, topY : 240, bottomY : 480, color: "#ffffff"};
notesArray["F"]  = {leftX : 960, rightX : 1280, topY : 0, bottomY : 240, color: "#ffffff"};
notesArray["Fs"]  = {leftX : 640, rightX : 960, topY : 480, bottomY : 720, color: "#ffffff"};
notesArray["G"] = {leftX : 960, rightX : 1280, topY : 240, bottomY : 480, color: "#ffffff"};
notesArray["Gs"]  = {leftX : 960, rightX : 1280, topY : 480, bottomY : 720, color: "#ffffff"};

...

// do something in here
var n = (note.slice(0,2)) ? note.slice(0,2) : "D" ;

x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (notesArray[n].rightX - notesArray[n].leftX + 1)) + notesArray[n].leftX;
y = Math.floor(Math.random() * (notesArray[n].bottomY - notesArray[n].topY + 1)) + notesArray[n].topY;
```

console log of n variable and notesArray[n].rightX

[image]
So, it **is** getting the number which is the coordinate of the rightX of whatever variable it is looking up, and is actually working properly.  My question is, why (or how) is it throwing this error but returning the correct coordinate and is there anyway to fix my code so it is not throwing the error?

Comment: I may be missing this but what is `note` defined as?

Comment: Your first line initializes `notesArray` as an array. But the next 12 lines assign to properties as if it's an object. While arrays are allowed to have properties, it's an uncommon pattern and I suspect it's not what you really intended.

Comment: What is the value of `n` when this happens?

Comment: @barmar any one of the notes in the arrays, so for example "Fs'.

Comment: Then you shouldn't be getting that error. Are you **sure** it's one of the notes?

Comment: @barmer I updated the question with an image of the console log, return n and then the line notesArray[n].rightX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that the single letter notes where the ones causing the error because it was looking for something that had two characters in it and must have been throwing an error whenever a single letter variable came in.
Switching the "A","B,"c" etc. over to "An","Bn,'"Cn", etc. fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the 2 console logs.
Between square brackets is an array key, not an array value.
Which means this `notesArray["A"]` is actually this `notesArray[0]`

```js
var notesArray = ["A","Bf","B","C","Cs","D","Ef","E","F","Fs","G","Gs"];
console.log(notesArray[0]);
console.log(notesArray["A"]);
```

To make it easy on finding the next steps to follow.
If you still want to use `notesArray["A"]`, define and empty array and than assign key and value pairs, like this: `notesArray["A"] = "A"`